# What functional programming language is this?

Tags: functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

```
let    f x y = sqrt x+y
  in let g = f 4
  in     g 1 + g 2
```

Is `sqrt(4 + 1) + sqrt(4 + 2)` or `(sqrt(4) + 1) + (sqrt(4) + 2))`

?

This appears in http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeFP/1989SPE/

Comment: could you provide a bit more context about where this language piece was found and the environment?

Comment: looks like a simple lisp like lambda calculus interpreted language that the authors were using.  the interpreter is written in Pascal.  http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeFP/Lambda/

Comment: @pad Actually it'd be a type error in OCaml because sqrt takes a `float` be `f` is called with integers as arguments. Also OCaml is not lazy.

Comment: # let f x y = sqrt x+.y in let g = f 4. in g 1. +. g 2.;;
    - : float = 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may well be none at all, as the syntax has been fairly established since at least the 1960s as functional pseudocode/lingua franca.

The date (revised in 1989) would suggest Miranda or SASL, but they both lean rather heavily toward `where` clauses rather than `let`. (I'm not even sure if they have `let`.)

So what it most likely is, if it's any specific language at all, is [Lazy ML](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeFP/LML/), which was developed at Chalmers in the early 1980s.